# Cambiar el action de un form dependiendo del valor de una variable

Tags: php, html, jquery, matrices, multitasking

Necesito cambiar el action de un form dependiendo del valor de una variable

Este es mi código:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            f = $('#flag').val();
            if (f = 1) {
                $('#multiple').attr('action', 'fax_cert.php');
            }
            if (f = 2) {
                $('#multiple').attr('action', 'fax_nocert.php');
            }
            if (f = 3) {
                $('#multiple').attr('action', 'usps_cert.php');
            }
            if (f = 4) {
                $('#multiple').attr('action', 'usps_nocert.php');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        include '../../components/conexion.php';
        mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
        header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
    ?>

    <form name="multiple" id="multiple" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="flag[]" id="flag" value="<?php echo $flag; ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Invoices">
    </form>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="cbx1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="marcado"></td>
                <td><b>Invoice Number</b></td>
                <td><b>Language</b></td>
                <td><b>Claim Number</b></td>
                <td><b>Claimant First Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Claimant Last Name</b></td>
                <td><b>DOS</b></td>
                <td><b>DOI</b></td>
                <td><b>Start Time</b></td>
                <td><b>End Time</b></td>
                <td><b>Provider</b></td>
                <td><b>Clinic</b></td>
                <td><b>Clinic Address</b></td>
                <td><b>Interpreter First Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Interpreter Last Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Certificate Type</b></td>
                <td><b>Certificate Number</b></td>
                <td><b>Insurance Company</b></td>
                <td><b>Insurance Address</b></td>
                <td><b>Insurance City</b></td>
                <td><b>Insurance State</b></td>
                <td><b>Insurance ZIP</b></td>       
                <td><b>Insurance Send Method</b></td>   
                <td><b>Insurance Fax</b></td>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $sql0 = "SELECT * FROM sw5hmgj4rwl_billing";
                $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql0);
                while($vec = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

                    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM sw5hmgj4rwl_company WHERE id = $vec[11]";
                    $r = mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
                    $cli = mysqli_fetch_row($r);
                    $clinic = $cli[2];
                    $cli_address = $cli[6].", ".$cli[7].", ".$cli[8]." ".$cli[9];

                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM sw5hmgj4rwl_company WHERE id = $vec[17]";
                    $t = mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
                    $ins = mysqli_fetch_row($t);

                    $ins_name = $ins[2];
                    $ins_address = $ins[6];
                    $ins_city = $ins[7];
                    $ins_state = $ins[8];
                    $ins_zip = $ins[9];
                    $ins_fax = $ins[5];
                    $ins_smethod = $ins[12];

                    $dos = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($vec[6]));
                    $doi = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($vec[7]));

                    $s_time = date('h:i a', strtotime($vec[8]));
                    $e_time = date('h:i a', strtotime($vec[9]));

                    $certified = $vec[14];

                    if ($certified == 'Yes' && $ins_smethod == 'Fax') {
                        $flag = 1;
                    }
                    if ($certified == 'Yes' && $ins_smethod == 'USPS') {
                        $flag = 2;
                    }
                    if ($certified == 'No' && $ins_smethod == 'Fax') {
                        $flag = 3;
                    }
                    if ($certified == 'No' && $ins_smethod == 'USPS') {
                        $flag = 4;
                    }
            ?>
            <tr align="center" style="height: 10px">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $vec[0]; ?>" form='multiple'></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[1]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[2]."-English"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[3]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[4]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[5]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dos; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $doi; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s_time; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $e_time; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[10]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $clinic; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $cli_address ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[12]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[13]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[15]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[16]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ins_name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ins_address ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ins_city ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ins_state ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ins_zip ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ins_smethod ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ins_fax ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php  
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

La variable que necesito capturar llevar por nombre "flag" pero la misma cambia dependiendo de algunas condiciones como lo pueden ver en el código. Dependiendo del valor de esta variable necesito que cambie el action de mi form que lleva por nombre "multiple". Como pueden ver, realizo un envío multiple, como el nombre del formulario, dependiendo de la cantidad de registros que seleccione el usuario y necesito que la variable flag cambie su valor dependiendo de las condiciones de dicho registro y que dependiendo de ese valor tome una ruta distinta en el action del form.

Agradezco de antemano por su ayuda.

Saludos!!

Comment: Las comparaciones se hacen con doble signo igual y tú estás usando solo uno, por lo que se analiza si la asignación se realizó correctamente. Cambia cada comparación, por ejemplo: `if (f == 1)`

Comment: Una vez que tengas seleccionada por id la etiqueta form puedes aplicarle setattribute() para cambiar el valor de action